# How can I add two Insets to the same image, one on top and one on bottom?

Tags: plotting, function-construction, inset

I would like to modify an existing code to add two Insets to the same image, with one at the top and the other at the bottom. Does anyone know how I can do this?

[image]

```
ClearAll[x, y];
x[t_] = Sin[50 t]/t + Cos[t];
y[t_] = Sin[30 t]/t^2 + Cos[t^2];
sub1 = Plot[x[t], {t, 1, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
   PlotRange -> All];
sub2 = Plot[y[t], {t, 1, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
   PlotRange -> All];
Plot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
 Epilog -> Inset[sub1, Scaled[{.3, .6}], Scaled[{0, 0}], 3], 
 PlotRange -> {-12, 12}, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

Comment: Just make the argument to Epilog a list: `Epilog->{Inset[...],Inset[...]}`

Comment: @lericr Didn't know you could do that. Why does this not work `Epilog -> {Inset[sub1, Scaled[{.3, .6}], Scaled[{0, 0}], 3], 
  Inset[sub2, Scaled[{.3, -0.6}], Scaled[{0, 0}], 3]}`?

Answer (score 5):

You need to be careful when you use the `Inset` with the 3rd argument as the position is relative. A more "intuitive" method would be to scale the image using `ImageSize` and then using `Inset` with only two arguments, the second being `Scaled`.

```
ClearAll[x, y];
x[t_] = Sin[50 t]/t + Cos[t];
y[t_] = Sin[30 t]/t^2 + Cos[t^2];
sub1 = Plot[x[t], {t, 1, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, PlotRange -> All];
sub2 = Plot[y[t], {t, 1, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotRange -> All];
Plot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
 Epilog -> {Blue, Inset[sub1, Scaled[{0.3, .6}], Scaled[{0, 0}], 3], 
   Inset[sub2, Scaled[{.3, 0.6}], Scaled[{0, 1.4}], 3]}, 
 PlotRange -> {-12, 12}, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]